# Calculating the duration an event in a time series data frame (python 2.7)

Tags: python, events, time-series, duration, dataframe

I have a rather large pandas data frame which is a time serie with a lot of different information for each time stamp (eye tracking data).

Part of the data looks a bit like:

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]:
    time    event
49  44295   NaN
50  44311   NaN
51  44328   NaN
52  44345   2
53  44361   2
54  44378   2
55  44395   2
56  44411   2
57  44428   3
58  44445   3
59  44461   3
60  44478   3 
61  44495   NaN
62  44511   NaN
63  44528   NaN
64  44544   NaN  
65  44561   NaN
66  44578   NaN
67  44594   NaN
68  44611   4
69  44628   4
70  44644   4
71  44661   NaN
72  44678   NaN
```

I would like to calculate the (time) duration of each event  as the max(time)-min(time) for a given event e.g. for event 2: 44411-44345 = 66

This duration I would like in a new column so that the data ends up like this:

```
In [60]: df
Out[60]:
    time    event    duration
49  44295   NaN      NaN
50  44311   NaN      NaN
51  44328   NaN      NaN
52  44345   2        66
53  44361   2        66
54  44378   2        66
55  44395   2        66
56  44411   2        66
57  44428   3        50
58  44445   3        50
59  44461   3        50
60  44478   3        50
61  44495   NaN      NaN
62  44511   NaN      NaN
63  44528   NaN      NaN
64  44544   NaN      NaN
65  44561   NaN      NaN
66  44578   NaN      NaN
67  44594   NaN      NaN
68  44611   4        33
69  44628   4        33
70  44644   4        33
71  44661   NaN      NaN
72  44678   NaN      NaN
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `groupby` and `transform`.  `max - min` is also called `peak-to-peak`, or `ptp` for short, and so `ptp` here basically means for `lambda x: x.max() - x.min()`.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("eye.csv",sep="\s+")
>>> df["duration"] = df.dropna().groupby("event")["time"].transform("ptp")
>>> df
     time  event  duration
49  44295    NaN       NaN
50  44311    NaN       NaN
51  44328    NaN       NaN
52  44345      2        66
53  44361      2        66
54  44378      2        66
55  44395      2        66
56  44411      2        66
57  44428      3        50
58  44445      3        50
59  44461      3        50
60  44478      3        50
61  44495    NaN       NaN
62  44511    NaN       NaN
63  44528    NaN       NaN
64  44544    NaN       NaN
65  44561    NaN       NaN
66  44578    NaN       NaN
67  44594    NaN       NaN
68  44611      4        33
69  44628      4        33
70  44644      4        33
71  44661    NaN       NaN
72  44678    NaN       NaN
```

The `dropna` was to prevent each `NaN` value in the `event` column from being considered its own event.  (There's also something weird going on in how `ptp` works when the key is `NaN` too, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: I get NaN for every duration

Comment: @MartinPetriBagger: that's strange.  Do `df.dropna().groupby("event")["time"].transform("max")` and `"min"` work?

Comment: same problem! It works for the small part used above, but not for my entire dataframe. I dropped the dropna() part. Then each NaN gets its own value and the i looped through the new column specifying what should be NaN and what not... that works.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over records using `groupby` from `itertools`. Group criteria shall be the event number. As you have the data properly ordered (all event codes related to the same event are not interrupted by others), there is no need to do sorting on even code.

`groupby` will iteratively return tuples (key, group), where key is the even code and group is list of all the records.

From the records, pick up minimal and maximal time and calculate duration.

Then, do your work to get durations as new field to your records.

There might be more efficient methods using pandas, which I am not aware of. Described solution does not require pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following work around to the posted answer by @DSM:

```
df["dur"] = datalist[i][j].groupby("event")["time"].transform("ptp")
dur = []
for i in datalist.index:
    if np.isnan(df["event"][i]): 
        dur.append(df["event"][i])
    else:
        dur.append(df["dur"][i])
df["Duration"] = dur
```

This at least works for me.